# Click desktop icon to execute python script and display on portable display

Tags: linux, icons, display, desktop

I'm using a BeagleBone Black with a 4.3 inches touch display.
I have an HMI python script that runs and displays a graphic window on that display.
I'd like to run it from an icon on the desktop (using Debian 11).

I have made a .desktop file :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Icon=/home/debian/MNIST/Python/N2D2.ico
Name=N2D2_IHM
Exec=/home/debian/MNIST/Python/N2D2_IHM.py
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

but I don't see how to tell it to use the display.
Normally to execute the script I run:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 python N2D2_IHM.py
```

Is there any additional syntax to write in the .desktop file to obtain the same result?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is : change the Exec line to

```
Exec=python /home/debian/MNIST/Python/N2D2_IHM.py
```